# Is battery calibration important for Android phones?

Tags: battery, charging, calibration

I heard that battery needs to be calibrated for a first few usages. I heard that battery needs to be calibrated every 40 charge cycles. I heard that i must not let battery get too low and not overcharge it. I heard that i must recharge battery at the end of every day until morning.

Is this all true? If i only have 1/4 of battery charge, should i place it on charge if i really need or wait until it depletes? I heard that when battery is fully charged, power adapter ceases to charge it but still emits green light. If that is so, then i guess there is no problem leaving it on charge for a long time?

Comment: I edited the question since shopping recommendations are off-topic.  But chargers and batteries will work if they have the appropriate specifications and adhere to them.  Find out the specs for the genuine batteries/chargers and compare to the cheap ones.  I usually get genuine parts from eBay, since they are cheaper there but guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android handles battery calibration.

Your battery life will be better if you keep it between 20% and 80% charged, and only charge it while it's off.  This is true for all Lithium Ion batteries.  It may not be realistic to adhere to that 100%, I sure don't.  You don't need to charge it overnight.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily most phone manufacturers do something pretty intelligent with android, there is hardware built in overcharge protection, basically when the battery gets to 100% it stops routing power from the AC adapter to the battery, and instead uses the AC power to power the phone.

But because this is true most (if not all) android based devices turn on as soon as they have enough power to, so charging while off becomes impossible.

I would agree that you should really only start charging at lower than 20%, as far as calibration goes i would say once a month seems fair, that is if you have a phone that stays off when plugged into AC. But it is likely that there is no built in hardware to prevent overcharge, so you may want to figure out how long it will actually take to charge before just going and plugging it in for 8 hours, as that could take a toll on your battery.

Comment: What do you mean stays off while plugged in? Shut down completely or in standby mode?

Comment: Most android devices?  Which ones don't stay off when switched off?  And "no overcharge protection"?  Huh?  That would be *very* bad, since you couldn't just leave it charging overnight.  I very much doubt that.  (Overcharge is potentially *very* dangerous)