# Looking for a consistent answer about battery calibration

Tags: battery-life, battery, charging, calibration

This forum is full of questions about battery calibration. The thing is, that either I'm blind or one answers contradicts others.

In particular:

1. For example [forums](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/40042/20449) says, that battery should be discharged to an absolute minimum. If you can power-on your phone, you should keep turning it on until battery is discharged so badly, that you can't turn it on. Sounds creepy and is in complete opposition to [Lie Ryan](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/33720/20449), who says, that "*a full discharge is never beneficial to LiON battery capacity*".
2. Again, [forums](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/40042/20449) says, that after full discharge and full charge, calibration process is completed, while [Logas](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/how-do-i-recalibrate-the-battery-of-my-phone) claims, that it needs a nearly-full discharge, full charge and again running battery fully flat.
3. Citing [forums](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/40042/20449) third time, he says, that battery formatting process should be undertaken only in rare, quite critical situations, when battery behavior became some sort of strange, while [Logas](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/how-do-i-recalibrate-the-battery-of-my-phone) says, that this should be done every 30-90 days.
4. All of them says about battery calibration at all, while [Matthew Read](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/10719/20449) says, that Android handles battery calibration and therfore (I assume) user should not do nothing about this.
5. Found some answers and comments saying, that both battery calibration and regular charging process should be done on turned-off phone, while others says that it is unusual with modern mobile systems to turn off phone completely very often.

So, can someone provide a consistent answer on these matters? Does the battery used in Android device require calibration at all? If yes, then how often, and what steps should be done to achieve this? Do I really have to run phone until it is really, really flat and do I have to charge it, while it is off?

Comment: One question at a time, and is bordering on too broad! BTW, [This](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/FV3LVtdVxPT) sums it up and **debunked** by the Google engineer mentioned in linky! *Android-related cargo cults* FTW!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is recalibrating the battery after flashing a new ROM really neccessary, and if yes, why?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29258/is-recalibrating-the-battery-after-flashing-a-new-rom-really-neccessary-and-if)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is battery calibration important for Android phones?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10692/is-battery-calibration-important-for-android-phones)

Comment: @Dan: You're marking my question as a possible duplicate, giving as an example a link to a question, which I already linked in my question and marked it as not enough answer / answer that contradicts others. Isn't that a little bit funny? I say: "I read it and I found it not enough", and you reply: "Duplicate! Already answered _there_"...

Comment: @t0mm13b I think this is actually one, not too board question: "_Does the battery used in Android device require calibration_". Possible answers: not at all / in certain situations / periodically. First answer ends discussion. Two others requires adding only few steps on how to do this. Steps, that will not contradict answers linked by me.

Comment: @t0mm13b However, upon further investigation on some other sources I'm beginning to think, that answer is: "**No**" (correct me, if I'm wrong). 2013 devices with Android handles battery calibration internally and answers about phones shutting down when battery was at yellow level seems to be coming from 2011, which makes them out-dated as for nowadays.

Comment: @trejder It doesn't stop being a duplicate just because you don't like the existing answers to the other question. Now, if your question is answered, there'll just be one more contradictory answer. You should bounty the original question to ask for answers "drawing from credible sources", or draw people's attention to it in other ways. If you wish to discuss what it means to be a duplicate question, or how to get new answers on old questions, you should ask on [meta].

Comment: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_charge_when_to_charge_table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are slightly different opinions around on this topic. To fully understand the issue, one needs to first understand how LiIo batteries work (which goes a little too far for our site, so please read details on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiIo#Prolonging_battery_pack_life)).

1. Lie Ryan is absolutely right: LiIo batteries don't take it well to be fully discharged.
2. It shouldn't be done too often. I'm not sure what a double-take should improve here.
3. Usually there's no need to do that "explicitly". If you think of how often you end up with an empty batterie (as it doesn't last long enough), calibration is already done as a side-effect (if you then fully charge). It's widely agreed that it should not be done more often than once in 60..90 days, so Logas might have mistaken the term.
4. See previous point :) I never saw reason to calibrate any of my devices' battery, though.
5. It certainly cannot hurt to do it with the device turned off, as then it's not being charged and discharged at the same time. I doubt it's really necessary, but it does no harm :)